# Exists a portrait location based Augmented Reality framework free to use?

Tags: android, augmented-reality

Wellcome all

I am searching for a location based Augmented Reality framework like mixare. It must show the camera view and must overlay on it POIS (locations) and show the distance to the POIS and a view. Mixare it's perfect for it, but is released under GPL license so I cannot use it.

Exists a framework for that, but with a permissive license (like apache 2 or lesser gpl)?

I must use it on a commercial app.

PD: I found this framework but unfortunately does not works with portrait activity: http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/  (it only works with landscape activity and haves a boolean to support simulated potrait but is not full support and is a must that it must work with explicit potrait activity (forced in manifest to portrait), so it doesn't works for me)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether u have used wikitude? Leading augmented reality sdk http://www.wikitude.com/ .

You can find the samples here. https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap/tree/master/Android. It uses cross mobile platform,phonegap.

Hope it might helps you.

Comment: unfortunately is not free to use. It includes a watermark in the augmented reality view, so i can't use it